# XML to Array and Array to HTML tables

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, visual-studio

How do I create an array from an XML file?
What am I doing wrong? And why i can't read this array?
I think i need to use StreamWriter for create HTML tables, but I am not sure.

```
class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sURL;
        sURL =  //link to XML

        WebRequest wrGETURL;
        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

        var singleOptIns = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).
        Element("Data")?.Element("Lists")?.Elements().Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "List").
        Select(el => el.Element("OptInMode")).Where(el => el?.Value == "SingleOptIn").ToArray();

        var DoubleOptIns = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).
            Element("Data")?.Element("Lists")?.Elements().Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "List").
            Select(el => el.Element("OptInMode")).Where(el => el?.Value == "DoubleOptIn").ToArray();

        Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

        Console.Write(singleOptIns);



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}}
```

Thanks a lot! 
XML =>

```
<Data>
<Lists>
<List>
<Id>111</Id>
<Name>LitGroup News</Name>
<Language>en-En</Language>
<OptInMode>SingleOptIn</OptInMode>
</List>
<List>
<Id>231</Id>
<Name>KH_test</Name>
<FriendlyName>Testname</FriendlyName>
<Language>en-En</Language>
<OptInMode>SingleOptIn</OptInMode>
</List>
```

Comment: What is the error if any ? and from where you are reading the xml data?

Comment: Use descendants :  XDocument.Load(filename).Descendants("List").ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng thx mate, but now i can't use "where" i need to create 2 array with <OptInMode>SingleOptIn</OptInMode> and <OptInMode>DoubleOptIn</OptInMode>
I try this `code .Descendants("List").Select(el => el.Element("OptInMode")).Where(el => el?.Value == "SingleOptIn").ToArray();` but it pick only OptInMode element

Comment: Try this : code .Descendants("List").Where(el => (string)el.Element("OptInMode") == "SingleOptIn").ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng, yeah thx already do it.  Can I use this array to create HTML table? Or fo xslt i can use only xml?

Comment: Are you planning to use XAML, java, jason, or straight html?